# How to create universal framework in xcode6

Tags: ios, ios-universal-framework

I know how to create a framework in Xcode 5. But in Xcode 6 how to combine both a simulator framework & a device framework? When I try to combine I get a code signing error. When I use `lipo` to combine both framework, I also get an error.

**Error:** `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65`

Comment: You are Creating static-library ?

Comment: your combine libraries (.a files) means that is (debug.a & release.a) once show me your lipo statement

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My solution to create universal framework in xcode6.

**Try these steps:**

**Step 1:**

```
File—> 
    New —> 
       Project —> 
           Framework & Library —> 
               Next —> 
                      Product Name
```

**Step 2:** Create custom class files

**Step 3**:

```
Target -> 
       Build phase -> 
           Headers,
```

Makes all header files into public. Now build in simulator & device.

**Step 4:**

```
File ->
    New ->
           Target ->
               iOS ->
                      Other -> 
                          Aggrigate ->somename eg: framework
```

**Step 5:**

```
From Targets —> 
    Custom aggregate target(Eg: Framework)—> 
           Build Phase—> 
               Add Run script
```

**Step 6:** Add following `shell code` in run script

```
///

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

**Step 7:**

```
Goto active scheme —> 
    Custom aggregate —> 
           Build
```

**Step 8:** Now right click framework from products in Xcode & click show in finder.

Check "Debug-universal” folder & get universal framework.

Comment: This worked great for me.  The only change I made was removing the -arch x86_64.  This was causing the problem of not being able to run on i386 simulators (anything before 5s).  -sdk iphonesimucator gives the compiler enough info to build for both i386, and x86_64.  If you explicitly specify one, it excludes the other. Thanks!

Comment: @Chad How did u remove -arch x86_64. Because When I removed from run script, it is still not running for Simulator.

Comment: @Chad : You need to try step 8. Then only you will get universal framework which supports for both device & simulator.

Comment: @Chad it's also not running in Simulator for me.

Comment: @AnsariAwais can you please let me setting the deployment target means? What you did?

Comment: Works in the device but in the simulator not found the references of the framework

Comment: @jose920405 :Right click framework from products in Xcode & click show in finder. Check "Debug-universal” folder & get universal framework which works in both device & simulator.

Comment: Yes man, i found the universal folder, but when drag to the proyect only works in the device.. I doing that in Xcode 7.3

Comment: This is working only in device but not on simulator, could you please help.

Comment: @Kashif Check "Debug-universal” folder & get universal framework. Universal framework only works with device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
```

with

```
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
```

clean build